# jQuery delay() doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, delay

I want an image to fade out before being deleted, but instead it's deleted instantaneously without fading. Here's my code:

```
$('img').fadeOut(3000).delay(1000).remove();
```

How to make the fadeOut effect visible by the user before removal takes place?

Comment: Delay works only for queue, mostly for animation. In your case, the chain goes further without waiting for animation to end. You have to do something like this `$('img').fadeOut(3000,function() {$(this).remove();});`

Comment: So I can't use delay() here, what can I do then?

Comment: Look at the updated comment. Like this or you can add `setTimeout` if more time is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.delay()` only affects effects queue(s).

Any chained method that does not involve an effects queue will be unaffected by the delay.

Try

```
$('img').fadeOut(3000).delay(1000).promise().then(function() {
    $('img').remove();
});
```

or

```
$('img').fadeOut(3000).delay(1000).promise().then(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout), as:

```
$('img').fadeOut(3000, function(){
   var $that = $(this); //cache your $(this)
   setTimeout(function() {
       $that.remove();
       //call your other functions
   }, 1000)
});
```

Comment: Are you sure in the function reference in setTimeout?? I think it will be called immediately.

Comment: Thanks it helps! What if I want to do something after remove(), like fading it another image?

Comment: @drake035 you could just call your fadeIn() method after remove, as remove() is synchronous in nature, your fadeIn() will be called after remove..

Answer (score 0):

As some have pointed out the delay works on a queue. I suggest using a function with a timeout as the complete parameter of `fadeOut([duration],[complete])`

[FadeOut Reference](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

[Delay Reference](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

**Example Code**

```
$('img').fadeOut(3000, function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("Removing now");
        $('img').remove()
    }, 1000)});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akupzfjb/)

Answer (score 0):

The `remove` method won't wait for the animations to finish as it's not an animation method. To get the removal to happen after the animation events, you can use the `queue` method to put a function in the animation queue:

```
$('img').fadeOut(3000).delay(1000).queue(function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Does it work if you take out the .remove() at the end? You may have to queue the actions so they don't all appear to happen simultaneously. Hopefully that helps!